# Deny reading part of a file in python

Tags: python, security, io, text-files

I have a text file for which I use two write functions: 1) Normal Write, 2) Secure Write.

Now when I want to read the data from the file, I should be only be able to read the data written using the "Normal Write" function and should not be able to read the data written using "Secure Write" function.

My idea was to use a dictionary for this using the key as a flag to check if the value was written using normal write or secure write.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Is the Python script the only way to access the file content? I.e. how do you guarantee a user doesn't just open the file with a text editor and look into your secret values?

Comment: This is one part of the project that I am currently working on. As of now,the python script is the only way to access the file content. Can I make the file not accessible through anyway other than the python script?

Sorry but I am being a complete noob here..

Comment: sounds like you are trying to create a stuxnet worm :)

Comment: If the user has direct access to the filesystem in which your "secure write" file is stored, it is virtually impossible to prevent user from snooping the content. I would first consider on solving this issue and then think about how to implement secure read/write.

Comment: ha ha.. no.. this is an acad project that I am working on.. A kind of a reference monitor :)

Comment: ok.. then the assumption is that the script is the only way to access the file content..

Answer (score 1):

its all a matter of how secure you want your data. the best solution is to use encryption, or multiple files, or both.

if you simply want a flag that your program can use to tell if data in a file is normal or secure, there are a few ways you can do it.

- you can either add a header each time you write.
- you can start each line with a flag indicating secure level, and then read only the lines with the correct flag.
- you can have a header for the whole file indicating the parts of the file that are secure and those that aren't.

here is a way i would implement it using the first option.

```
normal_data = "this is normal data, nothing special"
secure_data = "this is my special secret data!"

def write_to_file(data, secure=False):
    with open("path/to/file", "w") as writer:
        writer.write("[Secure Flag = %s]\n%s\n[Segment Splitter]\n" % (secure, data))

write_to_file(normal_data)
write_to_file(secure_data, True) 

def read_from_file(secure=False):
    results = ""
    with open("path/to/file", "r") as reader:
        segments = reader.read().split("\n[Segment Splitter]\n")
    for segment in segments:
        if "[Secure Flag = %s]" % secure in segment.split("\n", 1)[0]:
            results += segment.split("\n", 1)[0]
    return results

new_normal_data = read_from_file()
new_secure_data = read_from_file(True)
```

this should work. but its not the best way to secure your data.

Comment: This would not be feasible solution as I would have to deny the read operation itself at the beginning itself if the flag for that particular part of the file is flagged as secure. For that I think the third option mentioned above would help. How can I implement that?

Comment: can you please help with this?

Comment: @securecoding you should open a new question directly asking for a method to do this, after you have tried it yourself. and if you link it here i will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question I have posted:
[Read only a part of the file that was written using certain function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932340/read-only-a-part-of-the-file-that-was-written-using-certain-function)

Comment: just to clarify, the moment you call a `.read()` on the file in question, all its data is read, unless you read line by line, you can never limit the reading, and if you read line by line, you are, of course, reading the line before you parse it. if you are trying to prevent the system from reading the file, not simply prevent the user from accessing the data, then you were not very clear.

Comment: I was trying to prevent my own script from accessing the data written using the securewrite function.. Sorry If I was not being clear